# How do you sort in Excel using two pairs of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, sorting, microsoft-excel-2016

I am working on a spreadsheet where I have certain data organised in this format:

```
    Row 1: [Train Origin] 
    Row 2: [Train Destination] 
    Row 3: [Train Code]
```

The items are organised in columns.

What I need is to sort this information by pairs i.e. by one destination and one origin, for example: The first trains that would be listed would be going from destination A to destination B, then from B to A and then from C to D and D to C, etc. Then I would sort by train codes alphabetically. How could this be done using a native function or potentially VBA? I've tried using the native sorting function but without success.

Here's a screenshot of how Excel is currently sorting it:

[image]

And how I would like it:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to create a helper row with
an appropriate key and then sort the table by this key.

The top level order is a pair `Origin/Destination`
or `Destination/Origin`. 
One way to construct a group identifier prefix
is to join the pair, placing the lexicographically smaller one first
and using a separator, which is not used in the table, e.g:
both `Paris/SPI` and `SPI/Paris` will have a prefix `Paris@SPI`.
To make a key, concatenate this prefix with all the three fields
using separator.

For example, assuming that the table is in `A1:Z3`,
type

```
=if(A1<A2,A1&"@"&A2,A2&"@"&A1)&"@"&A1&"@"&A2&"@"&A3
```

in `A4`, copy/drag this formula to the end of the table row

[image]

and then use this row to sort the table data:

[image]

Sorted table:

[image]